# Prawn missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I've installed the `prawn` gem in my application.

```
gem 'prawn', :git => "git://github.com/sandal/prawn.git", :tag => '0.10.2', :submodules => true
```

Added the `pdf` format to the controller on `show` method.

```
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.pdf { render :layout => false}
  end
end
```

And created the `show.pdf.prawn` template file in my `views/order` directory.

show.pdf.prawn:

```
pdf.text "Hello World"
```

But when I try to load something like `/order/2.pdf`  I get a missing template page.

What could I do to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just missed to install the `prawnto` plugin:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto.git
```

Now it works!